# extend class from an external library and inherit its context in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have an external library and I am creating a service so that I can extend my service to that class and use its context.

```
class testApi {
  constructor(standardAxios, cachedAxios = null) {
    this.axios = standardAxios;
    this.cachedAxios = cachedAxios;
  }

  setAxios(standardAxios, cachedAxios = null) {
    this.axios = standardAxios;
    this.cachedAxios = cachedAxios;
    return this;
  }
}

module.exports = testApi;
```

this is the service I am creating and I can't access the axios context it has created

```
export class UsersService extends testApi  {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>, @Inject(axios)) {
    super();
  }

  async test(): Promise<any> {
    this.axios
       .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
       .then((e) => console.log(e));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `requestAxios`? For `UsersService` and `BigCommerceService` are you wanting Nest to handle the creation, or will you be calling `new` for both of these?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel i just need to access the axios context that comes from the extended class, i update my question

Comment: You didn't answer what I asked though. Do you plan to call `new` for these services, or do you expect Nest to create them for you?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question, if I am extending to an external class can nest create the service?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel either way I could extend to that class?

Comment: How can I make my question more clear then? Do you plan to call `new UsersService` or do you plan to let Nest create the instance of the class for you?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I could let nestjs create the instance of the class for me if

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve here, even with the comments. If you want Nest to be able to auto-create these classes, class types or `@Inject()` injection tokens need to be added to your classes and the classes and their dependencies need to be added to the related module's `providers` array. If it's something else entirely, please update your question with clear intent on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I just updated my answer, I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming*_ you have a provider token for the variable `axios`, this isn't how you inject it. Look at your `@InjectModel()`: notice how it has a `private userModel: Model<UserDocument>` after it? That's how your tell Typescript what the class variable is. If you don't need a class member, that's fine, but you still need the constructor parameter to be defined. This means, *at the very minimum* you need `@Inject(axios) axios: any`. You can set the type, I believe it would be `AxiosInstance` instead of `any`. **Now** you can pass `axios` on to `super`.

Do note that to do this in the first place, you **must** have a custom provider like

```js
{
  provide: axios, // same variable as is being passed to `@Inject()`
  useValue: axiosInstance // the actual instance to be passed
}
```

And this **must** be in the `providers` array of the module you're currently working in. This is called a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers).

These are some of the core concepts of NestJS, being able to inject via tokens and extending classes, so I suggest you read up on Typescript and go through the docs again to get a better understanding of what's available and how classes inherit from each other.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work yet, I am migrating from an express service to nestjs. :-(